How to design dual mode USB Type C power bank?
I want to design power bank that has 2 USB Type C ports and uses a large lithium battery inside.
I want to be able to use 100W power delivery when possible. I am absolutely overwhelmed by looking at USB spec and number of various datasheets from many different vendors.
So far I learned that nobody has a good all-in-one IC solution for power bank applications that includes USB-PD negotiation, bidirectional DC-DC, charge controller etc.
If 2 USB ports is too hard then maybe one?
The thing I most confused about is if I have to 2 power banks and I connect one to another one how are they going to negotiate who is who? For me it seems like if there is a big difference in charge levels one should charge another one at max speed. Once charges are equal then the process should shutdown.
I guess I need some high-level explanations of protocols before drilling down into the details.

Two or more ports are no different from one port. What is your concern about "2"?

My concern was about daisy-chaining 2 devices. If ports are fully bidirectional that shouldn't be an issue.

Start by looking for USB Hubs for specifically USB-C PDs. I recommend starting from higher level details and work your way further down in levels of detail. You're skipping some important processes before the USB-C PD gets utilized. It's like immediately starting to write code before you write out an algorithm. Architect before you engineer.

Also, at this stage in your project, don't worry too much about the nitty-gritty details. Just look at the application notes and diagrams so that you have an overall view of the solution you're trying to make. If you dive into all of the timing and electrical details, yeah, it's going to feel overwhelming.
